# Is the following inequality true for points in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

For distinct points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ and $(x_4,y_4)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is the following true?
$$
\big|||(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)||_2 - ||(x_3,y_3) - (x_4,y_4)||_2\big| \geq 
\min \{\big||x_1-x_2|-|x_3-x_4|\big|,
        \big||y_1-y_2|-|y_3-y_4|\big|\},
$$

where $||\cdot||_2$ is the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $|\cdot|$ is the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}$. I have tried to solve by brute force way but did not get success. I have also tried to get any counter examples but for the points I took, the inequality was satisfied.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: a counterexample is $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(1,0)$ and $(x_3,y_3)=(0,0)$ and $(x_4,y_4)=(0,1)$.

Comment: I am sorry to mention that all the four points are distinct. Please provide me another counterexample.

Comment: That's really not important, since either pair of points can be shifted. Change to $(x_3,y_3)=(900,900)$ and $(x_4,y_4)=(900,901)$ and the counterexample remains the same.

Comment: Thank you very much